# Displayed Error Message in Shipping Method not updating after save

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I've updated all scopes for FedEx for example. I've cleared cache and updated indexes and still no changes.

Any idea what I'm missing?

This is what's displaying when message applied:

> This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.

Comment: in my case my credentials were not working, please try to enter your credentails one more time.

Comment: Do all your products have weights? If none of the items in your cart have weights, Fedex returns no shipping rates and displays this message.

Comment: @AndrewNoble, yes products have weights assigned.

Comment: @Nickool, can you please elaborate? FedEx is calculating rates fine, but when products are selected for Canadian address, the error message is showing "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us." even though I have different content in the "Displayed Error Message." Any ideas?

Comment: debug and see which file the function getErrorMessage() is coming from we have multiple files having this, try to log"something".the function and see where it comes from and then tell us further info so we can help.